# Getting (negative?) ASCII values trying to load CSV. (APEX)

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, plsql, oracle-apex

I am having an issue reading in data from a CSV to an oracle database table via APEX.

I am taking in a CSV via file upload, passing the contents of that CSV into a BLOB datatype. Then iterating over the binary of that BLOB, and converting it to characters.

This is the article Im following: [Uploading CSV using Oracle Application Express (APEX)](https://nzchaudhry.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/uploading-csv-using-oracle-application-express-apex/)

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE 
  v_blob_data BLOB; 
  v_blob_len NUMBER; 
  v_position NUMBER; 
  v_raw_chunk RAW(10000); 
  v_char      CHAR(19000); 
  c_chunk_len NUMBER := 1; 
  v_line      VARCHAR2 (32767) := NULL; 
  v_data_array wwv_flow_global.vc_arr2; 
  v_rows  NUMBER; 
  v_sr_no NUMBER := 1; 
BEGIN 
  -- Script adapted from https://nzchaudhry.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/uploading-csv-using-oracle-application-express-apex/
  -- READ data FROM wwv_flow_files 
  SELECT blob_content
  INTO v_blob_data
  FROM   wwv_flow_files 
  WHERE  updated_on = 
         ( 
                SELECT max(updated_on) 
                FROM   wwv_flow_files 
                WHERE  updated_by = :APP_USER) 
  AND    id = 
         ( 
                SELECT max(id) 
                FROM   wwv_flow_files 
                WHERE  updated_by = :APP_USER); 

  v_blob_len := dbms_lob.Getlength(v_blob_data); 
  v_position := 1; 
  -- READ AND convert binary TO CHAR
  WHILE ( v_position <= v_blob_len ) LOOP 
    v_raw_chunk := dbms_lob.substr(v_blob_data,c_chunk_len,v_position); 
    v_char := CAST(v_raw_chunk AS CHAR); 
    dbms_output.put_line(Hex_to_decimal(V_RAW_CHUNK)); 
    v_position := v_position + c_chunk_len; 


  END LOOP; 
END;
```

The problematic line is: `dbms_output.put_line(Hex_to_decimal(V_RAW_CHUNK));`

I am using it to see why I am not getting ASCII values. The interesting thing is that I am getting some negative results (causing the rest of the query to fail) when there are no negative ASCII values...

Here is a subset of the output:

```
-17
-17
-17
73
116
101
95
32
67
95
100
101
31
66
117
115
31
32
68
97
116
```

Thanks,

Connor

Comment: I don't see where you are accounting for the character encoding of the CSV file. Independent of APEX and Oracle, to read a CSV file, you need to know what the author used for: character encoding, line ending, field separator, field quoting scheme (text qualifier) including how the text qualifier character is expressed when it is part of the field data, and if the first row is headers or data. And, unless you want to treat all the columns as text, the data types for the columns or rules for inferring them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve this myself:

To convert RAW to CHAR in Oracle: `utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(hextoraw(v_raw_chunk));`

Where `v_raw_chunk` is the hex data.